# Mongodb primary replica is generating a lot of logs

Tags: mongodb, logging

In my present setup, I have two nodes for mongo, one being primary and other secondary.
Logs for primary are generated very rapidly,(order of GBs per hour)
When I looked into logs, I found that most of them are the queries which I am executing on database.
I checked log level as well, it is set to 0.

It would be great help, if someone could point out why this is happening.

EDIT 1:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.getProfilingStatus()
{
    "was" : 0,
    "slowms" : 100,
    "sampleRate" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1599723810, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1599723810, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"E7OAaOj70Iop5nWO4EspQhnZvsI="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6849780058895155203")
        }
    }
}


rs0:PRIMARY> db.getProfilingLevel()
0
```

Comment: What are the current [profile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/profile/index.html#profile) settings?

Comment: @Joe, I have updated description.

Comment: With that setting, there will be a log entry for any query that takes longer than 100ms.  Are the queries that are logged tagged with durations longer than that?

Comment: yeah, all of them have time greater than 100ms. Increasing this limit should resolve the problem. Thanks for the help @Joe.

Comment: I am seeing that by default, profiling is off, and I am not modifying the profiling option in config file, then why am I getting all these logs?

Comment: Because mongod logs queries that exceed the time set by slowms.